# Not able to kill a task using kill -9

Tags: command-line, process, kill

I am trying to kill a process sublime_text using the kill -9 command. But the process is still there and so I am not able to open another instance of it.

```
 root@alwin-linux:~# ps aux|grep subl 

 root      3018  2.2  1.0 289008 61872 ?        Ds   12:30   5:27
 /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text 

 root   3037  0.0  0.2  65676 15364 ?        Sl   12:30   0:11
 /opt/sublime_text/plugin_host 3018 

 root      6702  0.0  0.0   4432   820 pts/1    S+   16:35   0:00 grep
 --color=auto subl 

 root@alwin-linux:~# kill -9 3018 

 root@alwin-linux:~# ps aux|grep subl 

 root      3018  2.2  1.0 289008

 61872 ?        Ds   12:30   5:27 /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text 

 root      3037  0.0  0.2  65676 15364 ? Sl   12:30   0:11
 /opt/sublime_text/plugin_host 3018  
 root      6705  0.0  0.0   4432   824 pts/1    S+   16:35   0:00 grep --color=auto subl
```

Comment: Using blockquotes *and* root?! You're really trying to make baby Jesus cry.

Comment: @Oli I don't understand

Comment: We have a code formatting option that makes monospaced console output easier to read. And you're logged in as root. And running Sublime Text as root.

Comment: yeah I tried the code formatting, but it is making the code more messy. Also I am running the sublime as root. Is that an issue ?I am mounting one drive over SSHFS and editing the code there. So I think I can do it with root permissions.

Comment: It can cause some pretty significant issues later on (the possibility it's going to litter you home directory with root-owned files), yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `D` in the STAT column means it's in an in "Uninterruptible sleep". That usually translates to something waiting for an IO command. These cannot be interrupted by kill.

You might be able to jimmy it back to life by unmounting your SSHFS mount. In general, using SSH with Sublime is a bit tricky. There is a [paid-for addon](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp) that claims to work well but I would work locally. Either `rsync` or script something up to deploy (Fabric+Git is great).

Comment: It is showing Device is busy for fusermount -u

Comment: @AlwinAugustin I'd try `sudo umount -f <path>` or `sudo umount -l <path>`

Comment: Do you have any references for those letters in the stats column? I't like to learn more about this.

Comment: @minerz029 [You mean `man ps`? See the "PROCESS STATE CODES" section](http://askubuntu.com/questions/360252/what-does-the-stat-column-mean-in-ps/360253#360253).

Comment: This sftp plugin is good but, it doesn't have a tree structure. So I think I need to use another editor like Aptana. This SSHFS mounting is not at all reliable.