# How can I tell state of program seemingly running

Tags: process, pstree

I had Firefox running, then (possibly) as a result of a key combination I don't recall, it quickly vanished from screen and Task Bar/Window List.

`ps ax | grep firefox` returns the below+the unneeded `grep firefox` line (Both `ps` and the GUI Task Manager, show firefox with seemingly unchanging RSS, VM-SIZE and 0% CPU usage):

```
johndoe      1916 36.6 14.0 923772 504372 tty1    Sl   13:30  12:15 firefox
```

****CORRECTED****
`pstree | grep firefox` returns:

```
init─┬─2*[ROX-Filer───firefox───25*[{firefox}]]
```

How can I tell what state the program is in?

Comment: `sudo strace -p $PID` will output system calls and signals from the program, if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a zombie process.

> Z    defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent.

If you run `ps ax | grep firefox` it will show you the status of the process, you can check against [this list](https://askubuntu.com/a/360253/169736) of status of the process (you must read the `STAT` column). Sadly, is unlikely that without fiddling with debuggers you can recover your data.

`tree` probably doesn't show you the process for the same reason.

Comment: Thanks Braiam - This is helpful (+1). From that list you referenced, it looks like it is in a `interruptible sleep` state. I have edited my question with the output of `ps ax | grep firefox`, hoping that you wouldn't mind elaborating on whether this means it can be recovered without use of debuggers (with a lot of time, I expect!). I see that other process' that are running fine also have a status of `S`*, so am hopeful that this is a good sign. Lastly, I assume reaped means cleaned up after?

Comment: @user66001 you should ask that in another question, like "how to recover a process from interruptible sleep state". I think you will be more luck if you ask in [unix.se] since there are pretty nasty Linux/Unix knowable people.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Historically though, I tend to get more answers/relevant info, on this sub site, than the generic Unix & Linux one, unfortunately. Lastly, I assume reaped means cleaned up after?

Answer (score -2):

Personally, I like `top` run from the command line. Works to find that one app that is slowing everything down.

[image: top in a terminal window]

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but how does this tell me if the program is frozen, running without a GUI window (If this is even possible in Linux), or (I believe is possible) detached from the GUI?

Comment: If does tell you its PID so you can kill the process. Isn't that what you're going to have to do anyway?

Comment: If I wanted to kill the process, wouldn't have spent the time writing up the question, and could have used tools mentioned in my question to do so, without using `top`. There is important work unsaved (realise this is my fault), and if there is any chance that due to my limited Linux knowledge, I am missing something that indicates it is still running, but the window is detached (or something), I want to know.