# What is the difference between Ctrl-z and Ctrl-c in the terminal?

Tags: command-line

Can anyone tell me the difference between <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>?

When I am in the terminal, both the combinations stop the current process, but what exactly is the difference between both?

Comment: I've asked a very similar question here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116959/there-are-stopped-jobs-on-bash-exit

Comment: An even closer match: [What’s different between Ctrl+Z and Ctrl+C in Unix command line?](http://superuser.com/q/262942/150988) on [SU].

Comment: yes i was successful in understanding the difference between both!!

Comment: One thing I want to add here, That most of guys ( in my professional circle too ) do not differentiate between them. And used CTRL-Z option to terminate command. Which is wrong practice. You must use CTRL-C on all these instances. As CTRL-Z simply put in background. So process not terminated until completed, Which may not be desire of User (most of time) when he press CTRL-Z to terminate.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

If we leave edge cases to one side, the difference is simple. <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> aborts the application almost immediately while <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> shunts it into the background, suspended.

The shell send different signals to the underlying applications on these combinations:

- <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (control character `intr`) sends SIGINT which will interrupt the application. Usually causing it to abort, but this is up to the application to decide.
- <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (control character `susp`) sends SIGTSTP to a foreground application, effectively putting it in the background, suspended. This is useful if you need to break out of something like an editor to go and grab some data you needed. You can go back into the application by running `fg` (or `%x` where `x` is the job number as shown in `jobs`).

  We can test this by running `nano TEST`, then pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and then running `ps aux | grep TEST`. This will show us the `nano` process is still running:

  ```
  oli     3278  0.0  0.0  14492  3160 pts/4    T    13:59   0:00 nano TEST
  ```

  Further, we can see (from that T, which is in the status column) that [the process has been stopped](https://askubuntu.com/a/360253/449). So it's still alive, but it's not running... It can be resumed.

  Some applications will crash if they have ongoing external processes (like a web request) that might timeout while they're asleep.

Comment: It's worth adding that it's also possible to run `bg` (instead of `fg`) to unsuspend an application that's been Ctrl+Z'ed *without* putting it back into the foreground; effectively giving you control of both the shell that started the application *and* the application itself, as if you had used `&` when starting the application. This often comes in handy when you forgot to start it with `&` :)

Comment: And you can get back to that process by typing `fg` again!

Comment: In case there are several jobs suspended or in the background : "jobs" list them, and "fg %n" or "bg %n" or even "kill %n" to put job %n in foreground, background, or kill it.

Comment: @Oli: Your second paragraph says, “The shell send[s] … signals to the underlying applications ….” No, the operating system / terminal driver sends the signals. (In a window system, the window manager may play a role.) Also, to be complete (although beyond the scope of the original question), you might want to mention Ctrl+\.

Comment: How does the session know which process group has to return to the foreground after doing either `ctrl c` or `ctrl z` ? It defaults to the SID (bash)?

Comment: @OlivierDulac, I tried to understand it by doing. But kill %1 said: Operation not permitted.  The task is running with & at the end as seen in `jobs`.

Answer (score 29):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is used to kill a process with signal `SIGINT`, in other words it is a polite **kill** .

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>  is used to suspend a process by sending it the signal `SIGTSTP`, which is like a sleep signal, that can be undone and the process can be resumed again.

However when a process is suspended, we can resume it again by `fg` (resume in foreground) and `bg` (resume in background) , but I can't resume a killed process, that is a difference between using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

How can we **view** suspended processes?

The `jobs` command gives output like this:

```
[1]-  Stopped                 cat
[2]+  Stopped                 vi
```

How to **kill** a suspended process in background?

By using the `kill` command:

`kill %n` where `n` is the number displayed by the `jobs` command. So if I want to kill cat: `kill %1`.

Comment: in accordance with other comments in this thread, correction: ctrl-z sends a SIGTSTP signal not a SIGSTOP.

Comment: Kill %1 tells me - Operation not permitted. Why so? Thanks

Answer (score 22):

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> suspends a process (`SIGTSTP`) and <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> interrupts a process (`SIGINT`)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Z

> On Unix-like systems, Control+Z is the most common default keyboard mapping for the key sequence that suspends a process

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-C

> In POSIX systems, the sequence causes the active program to receive a SIGINT signal. If the program does not specify how to handle this condition, it is terminated. Typically a program which does handle a SIGINT will still terminate itself, or at least terminate the task running inside it

Comment: Good job posting references.  But generally speaking, Wikipedia is not a very good source for technical referencing.

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 that is very true; I felt in this case the Wikipedia definition was decently sufficient.  I will look for more technical references in the future though!

Answer (score 11):

To put it simply:

- **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>** requests that the program **abort**.
- **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>** **suspends** the program and it remains resident as a background task.

  Suspending a program allows you to resume it later with the command `fg`. Remaining background tasks are killed when you exit the login shell.

Note that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> only *requests* that a program abort, and the program may ignore the request.  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> will suspend the program unless the program specifically overrides the request.

Answer (score 7):

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/262942/whats-different-between-ctrlz-and-ctrlc-in-unix-command-line) should help

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is used for suspending a process by sending it the signal SIGSTOP, which cannot be intercepted by the program. While <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is used to kill a process with the signal SIGINT, and can be intercepted by a program so it can clean its self up before exiting, or not exit at all.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. It sends `SIGTSTP`, which can be caught by the program. There are four different signals, which can suspend a program `SIGSTOP`, `SIGTSTP`, `SIGTTIN`, `SIGTTOU`. Of those only `SIGSTOP` cannot be blocked. The other three are used by the terminal to stop the process under different conditions.

Answer (score 6):

when you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, it means you send SIGINT to your process. like you type this command: `kill -SIGINT <your_pid>`. It will kill you your process. That why you cannot see it when issue **ps** command.
When you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, it means you send SIGSTOP to your process. like you type this command: `kill -SIGKSTOP <your_pid>`. It will stop your process, but the process still alive. So you can re-activate your process by sending SIGCONT to your process.