# apt install froze when uninstalling virtualbox

Tags: apt, virtualbox

I am trying to remove Virtualbox, and when I do, the terminal freezes and won't continue processing. These are the last lines before the freezing:

```
 -------- Uninstall Beginning -------- 
 Module:  virtualbox 
 Version: 5.2.10 Kernel:  4.15.0-23-generic (x86_64)
 -------------------------------------

 Status: This module version was INACTIVE for this kernel.
 depmod........

 DKMS: uninstall completed.

 ------------------------------ 
 Deleting module version: 5.2.10 
 completely from the DKMS tree.
 ------------------------------ 
 Done. 
 Loading new virtualbox-5.2.10 DKMS files... 
 Building for 4.15.0-23-generic 
 Building initial module for 4.15.0-23-generic
```

And when I press Ctrl + Z, the process is stopped, but I am forced to run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

And when I do, the problem returns to the same original point.
Any guess on how to resolve it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between Ctrl-Z and Ctrl-C in the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/510811)

Answer (score 0):

I ran:

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all virtualbox
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all dkms
```

and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem with the build of the current virtualbox dkms module stalling. Once it stalls, I can't exit the build process via Ctrl-C, Ctrl-Esc or any other key combination that I know of.

To sort it I tried purging both virualbox and dkms, and then reinstalling both, but this didn't work. It hung at 71% complete and didn't progress any further, so after half an hour or so I killed the terminal apt was running in.

In the end I manually deleted all the old virtualbox directories and files from /var/lib/dkms/ . Once I did this the build completed. Now, I just need to figure out how to sign the new modules so I can insert them into the kernel.