# Applications crashing when they are closed from terminal

Tags: command-line

I've notice that when I open an application from terminal, for instance

```
evince fileName.pdf
```

and I try to close using `Ctrl+z`, it actually does not close. Instead, it keeps open and when I try to close directly by "close button", it crashes and I receive a message like

> "fileName.pdf" is not responding

Does someone knows why this is happening?

Comment: I think you are confused about what ctrl+z does - see for example [What is the difference between Ctrl-z and Ctrl-c in the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510811/what-is-the-difference-between-ctrl-z-and-ctrl-c-in-the-terminal/510815#510815)

Comment: @steeldriver, you are totally right! Thanks!