# CPU performance on sleep command

Tags: bash

This is rather a beginner question. I wonder what happens when `sleep` command is triggered from a bash script, for example. That job would still running, with less priority?

Comment: I mean, in general, when our script is an infinite loop and we call sleep 120 (for example). What are the CPU decisions on that script? I think it should have less priority, because the script is like paused.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Please [edit] your question to make that clearer (I will delete my comment), I thought you were under the impression that you could use `sleep` to target other processes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically, [`sleep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/sleep.1.html) is the [GNU `sleep`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/sleep.c) program. This program calls the GNU function [`xnanosleep`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/lib/xnanosleep.c), which in turn calls the Linux [`nanosleep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man2/nanosleep.2.html) system call. And:

```
nanosleep()  suspends  the execution of the calling thread until either
at least the time specified in *req has elapsed, or the delivery  of  a
signal  that triggers the invocation of a handler in the calling thread
or that terminates the process.
```

So the process is, by definition, not running (whatever maybe the priority), but suspended.

Testing this out:

```
sleep 10 & ps aux | grep $!
[1] 25682
muru  25682  0.0  0.0   7196   620 pts/13   SN   04:10   0:00 sleep 10
```

The [process state](https://askubuntu.com/q/360252/158442) is `SN`:

```
   S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
   N    low-priority (nice to other users)
```

Ignore the `N`, I'd guess that's how it was when it started out. So the effective state of `sleep` is `interruptible sleep`.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. It was a good approach to check the process state while running it and see what those letters mean.