# uptime/tuptime Query

Tags: boot, bash, scripts, power-management, battery

Because my umpc handles suspend/hibernation poorly, I've had to script a shutdown after timed idle.

The main script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

idletime=$((15*60*1000)) # 15 min in milliseconds 
#idletime=$((5*20*330)) # about one minute, for testing 
idle=0
while [ $idle -lt $idletime ];do     
    idle=`xprintidle` 
    sleep 1 
done 
/home/jake/Scripts_Icons/Word_Shutdown 
sleep 2 
sudo shutdown -P now
```

The `Word_Shutdown` script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash 

if test $(wmctrl -l | grep "Microsoft Word" 2>&1 | wc -l) -eq 1; then      
    wmctrl -a "Microsoft Word"     
    sleep .2     
    xdotool keydown 0xffea + key 4     
    sleep .2     
    xdotool keyup 0xffea     
    sleep .2    
    xdotool key y 
fi
```

It works, but in order to monitor the battery life properly, I would like my uptimes during the sessions on one battery charge to be combined into one uptime.

Is that possible? I see that `tuptime` will show the uptime of the previous session and start monitoring the uptime of the current session. Is there a way to combine these outputs into a single readout eg `3hr 4 min` ?

The `tuptime` command output:

```
[jake@P3 ~]$  sudo tuptime -S 2 
System startups:    8  since  06:14:53 PM 06/20/2022 
System shutdowns:   0 ok  +  7 bad 
System life:            17h 50m 4s  

System uptime:          16.15%  =  2h 52m 46s 
System downtime:    83.85%  =  14h 57m 18s  

Average uptime:     21m 36s 
Average downtime:   2h 8m 11s  

Current uptime:     2h 9m 1s  since  09:55:56 AM 06/21/2022
```

The "System uptime" apparently combines all uptimes between shutdowns.

I have tried:

```
tuptime | awk -F'=' '/System uptime:/ {print $2}'
```

It works but, prints the seconds and the leading space as well i.e   `2h 52m 46s`. Is there a way to cut the seconds and the leading white space, leaving just the hours and minutes i.e. `2h 52m`?

Or does `uptime` itself have a handle that can similarly jiggled?

Comment: This seems like a typical example of what is called [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It works, but **in order to monitor the battery life properly**, I would
> like my uptimes during the sessions on one battery charge to be
> combined into one uptime.

In order to monitor the battery life properly:

- Identify your battery's device reference(name) with `upower -e` like so:

  ```
  upower -e | grep -i "batt"
  ```
- Get battery information by using `upower -i` with the reference(name) of your battery like so:

  ```
  upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  ```
- Refine the `upower -i` output to get only **state** like so:

  ```
  awk '/state:/ {print $2}' <(upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0)
  ```
- Refine the `upower -i` output to get only **percentage** without "%" like so:

  ```
  awk '/percentage:/ {print 0+$2}' <(upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0)
  ```
- Use the above knowledge in a script that checks every five minutes to run your shutdown command (replace `# Your shutdown command here` with your actual command) when your battery charge **reaches 8% or less** while it is in the **discharging state** like so:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    state="$(awk '/state:/ {print $2}' <(upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0))"
    percentage="$(awk '/percentage:/ {print 0+$2}' <(upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0))"
    [ "$state" == "discharging" ] && [ "$percentage" -le "8" ] && # Your shutdown command here
    sleep 300
done
```

> Because my umpc handles suspend/hibernation poorly, I've had to script
> a shutdown after timed idle.
>
> The main script:
>
> `#!/bin/bash ...`

- Your main script uses back ticks `...` for command substitution:

  ```
  idle=`xprintidle`
  ```

  While it will still work, back ticks for command substitution is considered a legacy feature(*old and might get deprecated in the future*) in bash so I recommend using `$(...)` instead like so:

  ```
  idle=$(xprintidle)
  ```
- The `sleep 1` call is too short for such uncritical task ... so I recommend extending it to say `30` seconds or even one minute like so:

  ```
  sleep 1m
  ```

> The `Word_Shutdown` script:
>
> `#!/bin/bash ...`

- Your `Word_Shutdown` script has two issues in this part:

  ```
  if test $(wmctrl -l | grep "Microsoft Word" 2>&1 | wc -l) -eq 1; then
  ```

  First, you don't need to use `grep "Microsoft Word" 2>&1 | wc -l` ... `grep -c "Microsoft Word" 2>&1` will output the same result.

  Second, quote the command substitution used directly in the `if` evaluation part to prevent possible word splitting like so:

  ```
  if test "$(wmctrl -l | grep -c "Microsoft Word" 2>&1)" -eq 1; then
  ```

> I have tried:
>
> `tuptime | awk -F'=' '/System uptime:/ {print $2}'`
>
> It works but, prints the seconds and the leading space as well i.e
>   `2h 52m 46s`. Is there a way to cut the seconds and the leading white
> space, leaving just the hours and minutes i.e. `2h 52m`?

Yes, and even better and future proof( e.g. if `System uptime` contains more than 3 fields e.g. `4d 22h 31m 54s`) like so:

```
tuptime | awk '/System uptime:/  {for (i=1; i < NF; i++) {if (i > 4) {if (i < (NF - 1)) printf("%s ", $i); else print $i}}}'
```

> The "System uptime" apparently combines all uptimes between shutdowns.

That is correct.

> Or does uptime itself have a handle that can similarly jiggled?

Maybe, the `-s` option will become handy in your case ... from [man tuptime](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/tuptime.1.html):

> **-s** | --seconds              Output time in seconds and epoch

Comment: This is incredibly helpful. Many, many thanks. I'm amazed at how much syntax is at your command. I've almost got your script running and I think I'll try to run it alongside a second script of `tuptime`

I have only a new characters left for this comment, so I'll post the `tuptime` output in a second comment because I'm hoping you could show me how to awk/print (not to file, output only) the "System uptime" which apparently combines all uptimes between shutdowns.

Comment: `[jake@P3 ~]$  sudo tuptime -S 2
System startups:  8  since  06:14:53 PM 06/20/2022
System shutdowns:  0 ok  +  7 bad
System life:          17h 50m 4s

System uptime:          16.15%  =  2h 52m 46s
System downtime:  83.85%  =  14h 57m 18s

Average uptime:  21m 36s
Average downtime:  2h 8m 11s

Current uptime:  2h 9m 1s  since  09:55:56 AM 06/21/2022`

I'm playing this but I can't just print the  `2h 52m`

`[jake@P3 ~]$  sudo tuptime -S 2 | grep -m 1 'System uptime' | cut -c1-9,10-15  | awk '{print $0,$6}'`

Comment: @jakfish Try this  `tuptime | awk -F'=' '/System uptime:/ {print $2}'` ... is that the output you want? ... If you want, you can add your script to your question and I will look into it and fix it as much as I can ... tomorrow though ... it's night time where I live :)

Comment: Again, your assistance is invaluable. Right before your last post, I went with this: `sudo tuptime -S 2 | grep -m 1 'System uptime' | cut -c36-41  | awk '{print $0,$6}'`

Which seems to work just like your command, but without listing the seconds, just hours and minutes.

Sleep well, thanks again.

Comment: You're very kind to look over my shutdown script. It's a shutdown after idle time, but before actual shutdown, it calls another script to find/save/close a Wine/MS Word doc (I posted over in wine forum but didn't get any hits, so I had to fumble mysel):

Comment: `#!/bin/bash
idletime=$((15*60*1000)) # 15 min in milliseconds
#idletime=$((5*20*330)) # about one minute, for testing
idle=0

while [ $idle -lt $idletime ];do
    idle=`xprintidle`
    sleep 1
done
/home/jake/Scripts_Icons/Word_Shutdown
sleep 2
sudo shutdown -P now`

Comment: Word_Shutdown script:
`#!/bin/bash
if test $(wmctrl -l | grep "Microsoft Word" 2>&1 | wc -l) -eq 1; then 
    wmctrl -a "Microsoft Word"
    sleep .2
    xdotool keydown 0xffea + key 4
    sleep .2
    xdotool keyup 0xffea
    sleep .2
   xdotool key y
fi`

Comment: I apologize for the brutal format of the coding, but apparently, this is the best "Add comment" can do.

Comment: `tuptime | awk -F'=' '/System uptime:/ {print $2}'` Your command is a better one than mine. It works better in xfce/panel/genmon. Is there a way to cut the seconds, leaving just the hours/minutes?

Comment: `sudo tuptime | awk -F'=' '/System uptime:/ {print substr($2, 1, length($2)-3)}'
  1h 38m` This seems to work, combining your command with `substr`

Comment: @jakfish I have added these comments to your question ... You can edit your question too, please see [site help](https://askubuntu.com/help) ... I answered with as much explanation as I could.

Comment: @jakfish To start your script after login and kill it on logout, change the method you are currently using to start your script  to ---> running it by creating a new startup application and adding a line like `bash /path/to/your/scriptfile` in the  "command field" see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1413670/968501) for example ... you might need, however, to specify the full path to the bash executable on your system that you can find with `which bash` ... I spotted your comment under the other member's answer by coincidence :) as I don't get notification unless a comment is under mine.

Answer (score 1):

Tuptime could narrow the range in their reports. As you need the current and just the previous one, use `tuptime -S -1`, check it that is right with table output `-t`.

And to calculate both uptimes together:

```
tuptime -S -1 --csv | grep 'System uptime' | cut -d\" -f6 | awk -F\m '{print $1"m"}'
```

Use the Tuptime csv output to parse it easily, match the target line, cut the field and extract the text before 'm'.

Comment: I'm so grateful for all this help. You've fixed a ton of things and taught me just as much. I put in all your script edits and everything seems fine except for one oddity (the oddity is persistent even with my original shutdown script) -- logging out brings me to the log-in page but then the machine shuts down without prompt. When I kill the shutdown script before logging out, logout/login is fine.

Is this a xprintidle issue or something in my script? Obviously, I can work around it by scripting a kill shutdown, then a logout command, but I'm interested in your opinion.

Again, thank you.