# How to make notify-send command work when an user logging into system in Linux?

Tags: login, notification

I tying make notification to an users about to ask administrate to check system is up-to-date or not.

Tried to add shell script in /etc/profile.d/notify-script.sh but it does not work.
Also tried to command notify-send to .bashrc but it works when the users open a terminal window.

I think I need to use at or cron task jobs for this task

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: @guiverc, you can't even suggest sotmething to try? Only this ? You're unbelievable for this community

Comment: @guiverc, Yeah, thanks. It helped.

Comment: Problem is solved here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413652/how-to-set-a-timer-that-starts-when-i-login-and-then-alerts-after-a-set-time

Comment: Elementary have https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/ as well as SE *Unix & Linux* so don't need this site.