# How to run a cronjob every 3 minutes and 2 seconds (every 182 seconds)

Tags: cron

I have a script that I want to run every 182 seconds.
As you know, cronjob precision is minutes so first I want to ask how can I run my code as a job every 182 seconds?

Secondly, I want to ask is there any better and efficient solution as cronjob is, to run a command periodically with a better precision than cronjob? I heard about some alternative options like `watch` command. However, I want a comparison between these options and cronjob and possible advantages or disadvantages each one has.

Comment: Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community. As your question doesn't appear to be related to the Ubuntu OS specifically, I'd suggest that you ask this question over on the Unix/Linux site instead (here's something I found that might help answer your question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/602792/60677). But in short, unless you're using a real-time OS (which the standard Ubuntu is not), the precision your looking for will be difficult to guarantee with any level of consistency (your best bet will be +/- a few seconds).

Comment: Related: [crontab run every x hours vs run when modulo hour is zero](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1449927/crontab-run-every-x-hours-vs-run-when-modulo-hour-is-zero)