# Something over-writes my start-up script defined calls to "xinput set-prop" and "synclient [property]=". How can I find out what is causing this?

Tags: bash, mouse, touchpad, synaptics

I am trying to enable synaptics touchpad "natural scrolling" on startup, based on the registry key "EnableNaturalScrolling".

```
    if [ $ENS -eq 1 ] && [ $VSD -gt 0 ] ; then
             VSD=$(synclient | grep VertScrollDelta | cut -d "=" -f2)
             VS_INVERT=$((VSD * -1))
             TPAD_ID=$(xinput | grep Synaptics | awk '{print $6}' | cut -d "=" -f2)
             xinput set-prop $TPAD_ID "Synaptics Scrolling Distance" $VS_INVERT $VS_INVERT
             synclient VertScrollDelta=$VS_INVERT
    fi
```

When this condition runs, all values are as expected ($ENS=1, $VSD=112, VS_INVERT=-112, TPAD_ID is what I need it to be)

The last two commands are two separate ways of enabling "natural scrolling on a Synaptics touchpad by reversing the Scrolling Distance.

`xinput list-props $TPAD_ID | grep "Distance"` shows negative values for this property I changed.

However, by the time GUI starts up, Scrolling Distance values are positive if I `xinput list-props $TPAD_ID`

How can I figure out why my changes are being altered or reverted by some program?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Startup script not executing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1450604/startup-script-not-executing)

Comment: I have proof that the startup script executes via logger debug statements.

Comment: How about delaying the execution of the script until whatever is messing it up has run?

Comment: Workarounds certainly exist but I would rather determine what is changing my code and why. I'll be sure to update once I figure it out!

Comment: The something that over-writes my changes is Xserver reloading the synaptics touchpad 39 seconds after boot. My script needs to run after this.

Answer (score 0):

The "something" that over-writes my changes is Xserver reloading the synaptics touchpad 39 seconds after boot.