# symlink to a bash script does not start on system startup

Tags: bash, scripts, symbolic-link

As per the subject, the symlink pointing to a bash script **is not executed when starting Kubuntu** 22.10.

If I click on the symlink **from Dolphin everything works**, the original script is executed.

```
andrea@Tehesyan:/etc/profile.d$ ls -l
totale 52
...
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root     71 giu 13 19:14 script-remapping-mouse-keys.sh -> /home/andrea/programmazione/bash-scripts/script-remapping-mouse-keys.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 andrea andrea  176 mag 19 11:24 script-resetta-wifi-al-login.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root    269 mag 16 11:25 script-start-pulseaudio.sh
```

The symlink is `script-remapping-mouse-keys.sh`, the other bash scripts run, **but they are not symlinks**!

Below is the original bash script, which still runs if I start the symlink from Dolphin.

```
#!/bin/bash
remote_id=18
mkdir -p /tmp/xkb/symbols
cat >/tmp/xkb/symbols/custom <<\EOF

xkb_symbols "remote" {
    key <AE04> { [ Home ] };
    key <AE07> { [ End ] };
    key <AE05> { [ Prior ] };
    key <AE08> { [ Next ] };
};
EOF

setxkbmap -device $remote_id -print \
 | sed 's/\(xkb_symbols.*\)"/\1+custom(remote)"/' \
 | xkbcomp -I/tmp/xkb -i $remote_id -synch - $DISPLAY 2>/dev/null
```

Where could be the problem? Thanks

Comment: Being a symlink is not an issue ... Symlinks to executable scripts are treated equal to the target script file i.e. if the target file executes directly then, symlinks to it will execute equally ... But, the issue might be this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1450655

Comment: this seems right, but sadly KDE has problems launching scripts, sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't, it's not reliable.
I could however pause at the beginning of the original script to wait for the session to load. Thank you

Comment: Using sleep didn't work, I fixed it by creating a .desktop file in ~/.config/autostart/