# Ubuntu gsetting at reboot

Tags: shortcut-keys, cron, reboot

I want to run following gsetting at reboot because something resets it I don't know what some keyboard language changer setting resets it.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options []
```

What I tried is:

```
 @reboot myuser '/usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options []'
```

I have also tried:

```
@reboot DISPLAY=:0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$(id -u)/bus /usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "[]"
```

The system is ubuntu 22.04 with Gnome...

Comment: Your command/s require a running graphical desktop/user session ... Either use a [startup application](https://askubuntu.com/a/1450655/968501) or a [user service](https://askubuntu.com/a/1475900/968501)