# How can I make an xinput set-button-map permanent?

Tags: touchpad, xinput

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 on a Lenovo ThinkPad P16 Gen 1.

At the bottom of my touchpad are left, middle and right click buttons. I am often accidentally pasting things by clicking the bottom middle of the pad. To avoid this, I can change the middle-click button to a left-click by:

`xinput set-button-map 12 1 1 3 4 5 6 7`

But when I restart my machine this resets and so I have to do this again each time - and as I understand it, the xinput for my touchpad won't be `12` every time (as it is in this example).

How can I make this change permanent or automate this mapping change each time I boot?

Comment: You cannot "make it permanent". You will have to re-do the setting every time you start  your windowing system. Look at your `~/.config/autostart/` directory.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I make this change permanent or automate this mapping change
> each time I boot?

The easiest way is to create a new [Startup Application](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html.en) for that and use this:

```sh
sh -c 'sleep 5 && xinput set-button-map 12 1 1 3 4 5 6 7'
```

... in the **<kbd>Command:</kbd>** field similar to [this example](https://askubuntu.com/a/1413670/968501) ... and it will be automatically executed on reboot and on login.

**Notice** that `sleep 5` will delay the execution of the command for five seconds (increase it if needed) to allow the graphical user session to fully load before `xinput` is executed ... This is needed because `xinput` requires a working graphical user session to execute and do it's job.

> and as I understand it, the xinput for my touchpad won't be `12` every
> time

That is possible if the device is e.g. removable and is connected to a different port the next time it's plugged in again.

While the ID might change, the device name usually doesn't ... So, you could look into the output of `xinput list` to get the name of your device and use that to get the ID like so:

```
xinput list --id-only "Exact Device Name" 2>/dev/null
```

... or even like so:

```
xinput list 2>/dev/null | grep --color=never -Po "Exact Device Name.*=\K[0-9]+"
```

... and that can be used in the above `sh` command string in place of the device ID (in a command substitution syntax `$(...)`) like so:

```sh
sh -c 'sleep 5 && xinput set-button-map "$(xinput list --id-only "Exact Device Name" 2>/dev/null)" 1 1 3 4 5 6 7'
```

or like so:

```sh
sh -c 'sleep 5 && xinput set-button-map "$(xinput list 2>/dev/null | grep --color=never -Po "Exact Device Name.*=\K[0-9]+")" 1 1 3 4 5 6 7'
```

... and your device ID should be automatically discovered.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit your .profile startup file you can execute this at startup.

.profile is located in the /home/{user} directory.

You can create the .profile file if it does not exist.

```
# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
# umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi

sh -c 'sleep 5 && xinput set-button-map 12 1 1 3 4 5 6 7'
```

Comment: The relevant part of this answer is identical to that of the Jan 10 answer.

Answer (score 0):

Find out the exact name of the device:

```
xinput list
```

[image: terminal1]

```
xinput list | grep "TM3127-001"
```

You can't rely on "Touchpad", "TouchPad", etc. I know this will never change.

```
xinput list | grep "TM3127-001" | grep -Eo 'id=[0-9]{1,2}'
```

Isolate the id number (above), then `grep` out the numbers (below):

```
xinput list | grep "TM3127-001" | grep -Eo 'id=[0-9]{1,2}' | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,2}'
```

[image: terminal2]

```
sudo nano /path/to/script/my_script.sh
```

Use the following script for `my_script.sh`.
Replace `YOUR_UNIQUE_STRING` with your device name, where mine was `TM3127-001`.
Save & exit.

```
#!/bin/bash

device_id=$(xinput list | grep "YOUR_UNIQUE_STRING" | grep -Eo 'id=[0-9]{1,2}' | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,2}')

xinput set-button-map "$device_id" 1 1 3 4 5 6 7

exit 0
```

Change mode to executable: `sudo chmod +x /path/to/script/my_script.sh`

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Put the following at the end of the file:

```
/path/to/script/my_script.sh start
```

Now save, exit & reboot. Your button mapping is now permanent.