# vim using up 100% CPU, can't kill it

Tags: vim, kill, top

Every so often (about once a month), my vim starts eating resources like crazy, and I'm unable to kill it. Here's an example:

[image]

I ran:

```
kill 13799
```

To no effect. I would like to know:

1) Could be vim going haywire due to something else? I use it to write code in and it's usually when the code is running that I get an issue.
2) If not, why would vim do this?
3) How can I kill it? Currently, I have to reboot every time.

Thanks )

Comment: `kill -9 $(pidof vim)`

Comment: It would be hard to figure out the reason, are you editing some very large files? Did you copy/paste some text by mistake while in command mode (This can run the commands which may need a while process)? When you run the code, is it modifying some larger files that you have open in vim while you have `autoread` enabled? Do you have lots of plugins installed? etc.

Comment: Maybe clearing `vim cache` in `~/.viminfo` fix 
 it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816719/clear-certain-criteria-from-viminfo-file

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'll try clear cache and kill -9 next time. @Dan maybe plugins are the issue yea, I have quite a few.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kill` is quite polite by default, it raises the `SIGTERM` signal. With this, the application is expected to see and handle the signal (eg quit) but that is completely up to the application to be able and willing.

You can see here that vim is "running" —[that's what the R means](https://askubuntu.com/a/360253/449)— and that means it's likely too busy to intercept and process the signal. If it's been doing this a while, you may have stumbled on a bug.

Either which way, if you want to forcibly nuke it, you can use other signals. `SIGKILL` is a popular choice.

```
kill -9 13799
```

It cannot be ignored as it interrupts the current process (with some run-state exceptions, like zombie or other uninterruptible states).

This is an extremely high-level look at this. Take a look at `man 7 signal` to zoom in.