# How to kill Firefox without unplug power if even 'sudo kill -9' can't?

Tags: 18.04, firefox, process

This question may look similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87074/how-to-kill-the-process-that-sudo-kill-9-cant-kill-without-reboot) or [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360211/not-able-to-kill-a-task-using-kill-9) but the difference here is that the process in question is Firefox, i.e. it is under user space and it is not related to mounting stuff.

In my case the rest of the system was responsive, only Firefox got halted.

What else could stop `sudo kill -9` to work and how could I go back to a healthy environment without physical unplugging the power (even reboot didn't work) ?

Comment: Huh? You're saying that firefox was still running *after* a reboot?

Comment: There should be several PIDs for Firefox (not ony one) - Try with `sudo pkill -f firefox` or `pidof firefox | xargs sudo kill -9`